# Custom function works for just a single cell , but not for a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm doing excel sheet for employees salary . It's include 31 columns for 31 days work.
each day has a period time (duration and leaving) as a text data type (like: **"7 am-3 pm"**) .
My function will get the duration of working at that day (which = 8 hours) .

It's works for one cell ,but it's not works with a range of cells !
like: (7 am-3 pm),(7 am-5 pm),(8 am-3 pm),...

> Error text : "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

My function code for one cell :

```
(IF(ISBLANK(E79);0;((IF(TIMEVALUE(REPLACE((E79);1;SEARCH("-";(E79);1);""))
<TIMEVALUE(LEFT((E79);SEARCH("-";(E79);1)-1));(TIMEVALUE(REPLACE((E79);1;
SEARCH("-";(E79);1);""))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT((E79);SEARCH("-";(E79);1)-1)))+
1;(TIMEVALUE(REPLACE((E79);1;SEARCH("-";(E79);1);""))-
TIMEVALUE(LEFT((E79);SEARCH("-";(E79:AI79);1)-1)))))*24)))
```

---

It is not work when I replace (E79) to (E79:AI79) . And also it not works when I put the function with the rang inside **SUM** function !

I don't use **SUMPRODUCT** , because it should make 31 arrays for each day (each single cell) .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=(MAX(--TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"))-MIN(--TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-")))*24
```

Shorter formula using `LET()` function.

```
=LET(x,--TEXTSPLIT(A2,"-"),(MAX(x)-MIN(x))*24)
```

[image]

Comment: My excel version is 2013 , "TEXTSPLIT" and "LET" are not found .

Comment: @Na'il Then `FILTERXML()` may work.

Comment: Try this formula- `=(MAX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))-MIN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))*24`

Answer (score 0):

This example is for data in row 1 from column A to AE (A1:AE1)
-Some columns are hidden to fit the photo in width-
And this is the formula in cell AF1, Press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER  (it is an array formula)

```vb
=SUM(IF(A1:AE1="";0;(MID(A1:AE1;SEARCH("-";A1:AE1)+1;6) - LEFT(A1:AE1;SEARCH("-";A1:AE1)-1))*24))
```

If your data updated twice  eg. initial "10 πμ" and final "10 πμ-10 μμ"
you can try the following formula which ignores incomplete cells.
I try OR(...) but works only with IF inside IF...:

```vb
=SUM(IF(A1:AE1="";0;IF(LEN(A1:AE1)<7;0;(MID(A1:AE1;SEARCH("-";A1:AE1)+1;6) - LEFT(A1:AE1;SEARCH("-";A1:AE1)-1))*24)))
```

[image]